# Android Studio Assets file cannot be accessed in WebView

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, jpeg, android-assets

I have been trying to figure out almost 2 weeks.
I have read previous posts and tried the proposed solutions but they didn't work for me.

Iam using Android Studio, I need Webview to access a local Jpg stored in Android Assets file.

Here is my code:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
startWebView("file:///android_asset/railchinese.jpg");
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

private void startWebView(String url) {
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Here is the Assets location screen:

[image]

Kindlly let me know where is the mistake?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
String htmlData="<img src= railchinese.png>";

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlData, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```